# Token Contract Verified and Signed on Mainnet Does Not Show MINT Function

Tags: tokens, erc-20, contract-deployment, mint

The Token Contract Address https://etherscan.io/address/0xa2e7a0d1cfeda4d3977277265e205f6092d02e3b was successfully tested on Ropsten (See Ropsten Contract Address 0x82Bc5871e30FB2C00A3E5B5E6475A2baD88978ba).

Now exactly the same contract has been deployed, verified and signed on Mainnet [image], However I am unable to interact with the main functions, specifically with the MINT Function.[image]

Etherscan Helpdesk tickets #120001 and #120314 have been opened and I have interacted with Mr./Ms. Raja C, but he/she has not been able to address/resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi! Could you fill in a few more details, such as the address on mainnet, and confirmation that you were able to mint on Ropsten? Thanks!

Comment: Address on Mainnet https://etherscan.io/address/0xa2e7a0d1cfeda4d3977277265e205f6092d02e3b                                  Confirmations on Ropsten https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x82bc5871e30fb2c00a3e5b5e6475a2bad88978ba

Comment: There is nothing that etherscan helpdesk can do about this, since `function _mint(address account, uint256 value) internal` is obvious not exposed to external callers!

Comment: My wallet 0xbC57B9bb80DD02c882fcE8cf5700f8A2a003838E is the creator wallet, see the Contract; ; Therefore I should be the ONLY one able to see and execute the MINT function.

I am still waiting for an answer from the Ethereum Team...

Comment: The function is internal, no one outside the contract can call it!

Comment: The _mint Function is called at the end of the contract by the mintFVP function. The exact combination of functions exist today on the following contracts https://etherscan.io/address/0x349c9a0afbe8c8e08a6bd8a2e925f9ec5ae7d2c9#code and https://etherscan.io/address/0x29fb4CEe43155bAAB885897f0e96B1F0572a1E86#code  See the contract    constructor() public {

  function mintFVP() public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    require (stage <=10);
    _mint(creator, tokensToMint[stage]);
    stage = stage.add(1);
    return true;
  }
}   I AM STILL WAITING FOR AN ANSWER BY THE ETHEREUM TEAM

Comment: You're littering the comment section. Post all the relevant information (and ONLY the relevant information) as part of your question. There is no `mintFVP` function in the contract that you've linked in your question! There is no such thing as "THE ETHEREUM TEAM" anywhere that I'm aware of. Please post everything in plain text (no screenshots or images), so that others can refer to it easily. Your question is completely baffled, with a ton of unclear information, like "Mint Functions", which any reader needs to go into your contract and try to figure out what exactly is meant by that!

Answer (score 0):

My wallet 0xbC57B9bb80DD02c882fcE8cf5700f8A2a003838E is the creator wallet [image]; See the Contract [image]; Therefore I should be the ONLY one able to see and execute the MINT function.

I am still waiting for an answer from the Ethereum Team...

Comment: Don't post more details to your question as part of the answer! Also, as I've explained to you in a comment to the question, the function is internal, no one outside the contract can call it!

Comment: The _mint Function is called at the end of the contract by the mintFVP function. The exact combination of functions exist today on the following contracts https://etherscan.io/address/0x349c9a0afbe8c8e08a6bd8a2e925f9ec5ae7d2c9#code and https://etherscan.io/address/0x29fb4CEe43155bAAB885897f0e96B1F0572a1E86#code  See the contract    constructor() public {

  function mintFVP() public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    require (stage <=10);
    _mint(creator, tokensToMint[stage]);
    stage = stage.add(1);
    return true;
  }
}   I AM STILL WAITING FOR AN ANSWER BY THE ETHEREUM TEAM

Comment: You're littering the comment section. Post all the relevant information (and ONLY the relevant information) as part of your question. There is no `mintFVP` function in the contract that you've linked in your question! There is no such thing as "THE ETHEREUM TEAM" anywhere that I'm aware of. Please post everything in plain text (no screenshots or images), so that others can refer to it easily. Your question is completely baffled, with a ton of unclear information, like "Mint Functions", which any reader needs to go into your contract and try to figure out what exactly is meant by that!

Comment: If you actually read the entire contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xa2e7a0d1cfeda4d3977277265e205f6092d02e3b#code, specially at the end, you will see that the function mintFVP() calls the _mint function; as I said, these two functions already exist on the two existing and working token contracts mentioned on my previous comment and it was successfully tested on the Ropsten network, also noted.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause of the issue identified:

When I deployed FVP_Tokel.sol on Ropsten via Truffle/Infura it migrated and worked just fine; but when I started experiencing issues while deploying on Mainnet (the prompt would just sit there for hours after compiling) I decided to try Remix (granted, the new fancy version) which in fact I do not recall there was an area where one would specifically select FVP_Token.sol.

It is very possible however that since it has been a while I mess with Remix to begin with, that I totally forgot about ensuring that the master contract (FVP_Token.sol) was selected before it was deployed, or I simply did not see the area where to select the contract once it has been loaded.

I will re-deploy FVP_Token.sol using the OLD VERSION of Remix, ensuring this time that the master contract FVP_Token.sol has been chosen.